# Date needs to be validated for greater than today's date #DocuSignAPI

Tags: docusignapi

We need to validate a date field(Data Field) is greater than today's date in DocuSign Envelope. How can we validate a Date greater than today's date in DocuSign Data Field?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to set the properties of a Data Field (i.e., text box) in DocuSign such that it requires a Date AND requires that Date to be greater than today's date. You can easily set Data Field properties such that only a Date will be considered valid input -- the show-stopper is the inability to dynamically require a date in a specific range (for example, greater than today's date).

On the off-chance that I'm missing something (and it IS possible to do what you describe), you might consider also posting your question to the DocuSign Community Forum (http://community.docusign.com/t5/Sending-Options-and-Features/bd-p/Community-Information).  Although that forum won't provide info about using the DocuSign API, it's a good place to ask general feature/functionality questions....which can be valuable, since if you're able to figure out how to do something via the DocuSign UI (web console), it's usually straightforward to translate that to API implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Kim is right in that there is no way through the "out-of-the-box" functionality to only allow dates after a certain time to be entered, however if you're using the DocuSign API you could:

1. Ask the user to enter a date BEFORE opening the envelope.
2. Validate the date is in the acceptable range you are seeking.
3. Add the data field to your envelope with the already validated date and make read-only so it can't be changed.